# Uploadify onComplete Queue change

Tags: php, jquery, events, queue, uploadify

I'm trying to customise Uploadify. When an upload is complete I want to change the queue item associated with that upload to reflect the response from my upload script.

E.g. Upload error: Background changes to red and response is added.

Does anyone with knowledge of Uploadify know how to get an upload's associated queue item so I can modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to the uploadify options the option "overrideEvents : [list here all the function, which you will change],". E.g. function "onUploadError" report about errors in a time uploading, "onUploadSuccess" - report about success upload. Full list of this functions you will find in the not compressed "jquery.uploadify-3.1.js"